Managing EC2 instance IP assignment priority
I'm trying to get the primary IP setup correctly for an EC2 instance. The instance is created with terraform as follows:
module "router" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  name = "udp-router-loadtest-router"

  private_ip             = "10.0.2.10"
  secondary_private_ips  = ["10.0.2.11"]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  ami                    = "ami-0929f698754f34ba7"
  instance_type          = "c7gn.xlarge"
  key_name               = "udp-router-loadtest-key"
  monitoring             = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.instance.id]
  subnet_id              = aws_subnet.router.id

  tags = {
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

What I would like is for the instance to always use the IP 10.0.2.10 for any network traffic by applications running on the instance. If I make a DNS query, then the query should come from this IP. The second should only be used as the source address for packets forwarded to backend instances.
Now I see the following assigned to the instance:
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:ec:e9:b8:f7:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s5
    inet 10.0.2.11/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.2.10/24 metric 100 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global secondary dynamic ens5
       valid_lft 2571sec preferred_lft 2571sec
    inet6 fe80::10ec:e9ff:feb8:f735/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I'm unable to tell whether the setup is correct. If I make a DNS query, tcpdump does tell me that the request is going out with source IP 10.0.2.10. However, is this guaranteed and not just luck?
